# Storing table content to HTML5 local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

So I have multiple input boxes in HTML. Then I create a table with jquery and on a click of a button I store values from the input boxes into my table.
What I don't know how to do is how to store those values into local storage and the when the page reloads show them in the table.

This is my code for adding a new line to the table:

```
    $().ready(function(){
      $("#addLine").click(function(){
        var chore = $("#chore").val();
        var type= $("#type").val();
        var importance = $("#importance").val();
        counter++;
        var newLine = "<tr><td>"+counter+"</td><td>"+chore+"</td>   
        <td>"+type+"</td><td>"+importance+"</td><td>"+date+"</td></tr>";
        $("#tabela tbody").append(newLine);
});
});
```

Comment: what is the problem with store values by `localStorage`

Comment: ok you are having multiple rows and pushing new rows.

Comment: For thati suggest you to make `array` of `object` means a `JSON` and update (push item) that `json` on every new row added by `localStorage`

Comment: please check my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use `setItem` method of [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage):

```
localStorage.setItem( "tabledata", $("#tabela").html() );
```

Later you can fetch it like this:

```
var tabledata  = localStorage.getItem( "tabledata" );
$("#tabela").html( tabledata );
```

Comment: I know how to do this for one item. The problem is that I have to store multiple chores and types and dates...

Comment: @xxm0dxx can you be more specific with your requirements? what is stopping you from adding multiple types of information?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make a array

```
var tableItems = [];
//getting old items
tableItems = localStorage.getItem("tabledata");

//push item on new add
tableItems.push({
"chore":"",
"type":"",
"importance":"",
"date":""
});
```

You have to store it in

```
localStorage.setItem( "tabledata", tableItems ) );
```

Generate `<table>` from this `JSON` stored in `localStorage`

Answer (score -1):

to set a item in browser local storage:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", value);
```

to get a item from browser local storage:

```
var value = localStorage.getItem("key");
```