# Why wouldn't my code run? (Trying to add a row from another page)

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am trying to insert a row into a table from another page. Using Javascript. I don't want to use ajax or jQuery because it seems a bit too complicated.

I am tackling this problem through:

1. Get the id table element from the other page
2. Insert the row when the button is clicked
3. Save the changes

I experimented with different things from the w3 schools website. I noticed the changes don't save after the page is reloaded. Why?

What I want is to be able to add a row from the second.php to the table in index.php.

My code is below: The Javascript runs but nothing is being added:

index.php

```
<a href="secondPage.php">Go to the second page</a>
<br>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <td>Row1 cell1</td>
        <td>Row1 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row2 cell1</td>
        <td>Row2 cell2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Row3 cell1</td>
        <td>Row3 cell2</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
    localStorage.setItem('table', $('#myTable').val());
</script>
```

secondPage.php

```
<a href="index.php">Go to the first page</a>
<br>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Add to table</button>

<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var table = localStorage.getItem('table');
        var row = table.insertRow(0);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = "NEW CELL1";
        cell2.innerHTML = "NEW CELL2";
        window.alert(document.getElementById("myTable").rows.length);

    }
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code at all? Check the console for errors. The JavaScript code in `index.php` should be throwing an exception.

Comment: I'm sorry but you are already using jQuery, did you make sure to import the library?

Comment: I tested, the localStorage item is empty. `console.log($('#myTable').val());` returns nothing.

Comment: The console is not throwing any errors. But guys am I on the correct path here?

Comment: 1. `$('#myTable').val()` should give you an error. `val()` method is exclusive to form controls, so tables are not form controls (ex. input, textarea, select, etc). 2. Sharing data between two pages is far simpler with AJAX than with `localStorage`. `localStorage` only stores strings, but with AJAX the sky is the limit and besides it's older than dirt so every scenerio has been covered a billion times before.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save an HTMLElement using LocalStorage, which I believe doesn't work as LocalStorage will only save a key-value pair with strings.

So what I would do is:

1 - Save a stringified version of your table

```
document.getElementById('myTable').innerHTML
```

2 - On the second page, create a HTMLElement using the string you saved.

```
var table = document.createElement('table');
table.innerHTML = localStorage.table;
```

3 - Edit the table you created on the second page, using table.insertRow, table.insertCell, etc.

4 - Save everything again on localStorage using step 1 hint.

5 - Make sure you load your edited table from localStorage on page 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the table into localStorage, like instructed at [Storing table content to HTML5 local storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34691804/storing-table-content-to-html5-local-storage). But it is different from the method shown above in the original question.

> Use setItem method of localStorage:

```
localStorage.setItem( "tabledata", $("#myTable").html() );
```

> Later you can fetch it like this:

```
var tabledata  = localStorage.getItem( "tabledata" );
$("#tablea").html( tabledata );
```

However, `row = table.insertRow(0)` casted error in my test: `Uncaught TypeError: table.insertRow is not a function`. Though I figured out a solution later but it is off the topic.